# Loring exercise 1.5 b.) Concluding that $h(a, b) = \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 - a^2 - b^2}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 - a^2 - b^2}}\right)$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

After finding the inverse of $h: B(0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $h(a, b) = (h_1(a, b), h_2(a, b)) = \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 - a^2 - b^2}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 - a^2 - b^2}}\right)$, in the exerise 1.5 b.) (pp. 8-9) of Loring's *An Introduction to Manifolds*, Loring ask to *"conclude"* that $h$ is a diffeomorphism of the open disk $B(0, 1)$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am apparently a bit rusty with my multivariable calculus, so is there a more convinient way to *"conclude"* the diffeomorphism of $h$ other than checking that the partial derivatives $\partial h_1 / \partial a, \partial h_1 / \partial b, \partial h_2 / \partial a, \partial h_2 / \partial x$ of $h$ (similar for its inverse $h^{-1}$) exist at an arbitrary point $(x, y) \in B(0, 1)$ (resp. $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stament holds in any dimension $n\geq2$. Here is a simple proof.

Clearly $F:\mathbf{x}\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2}}\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\intercal$ and $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2:=x^2_1+\ldots + x^2_n$, is a differentiable bijective function from $B(0;1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Notice that if
$$\mathbf{u}:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2}}\mathbf{x}$$
then
$$\|\mathbf{u}\|^2_2=\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2}{1-\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2}$$
and so,
$$\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_2=\frac{\|\mathbf{u}\|^2_2}{1+\|\mathbf{u}\|^2_2}$$
Hence
$$\mathbf{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\|\mathbf{u}\|^2_2}}\mathbf{u}$$

The map $G:\mathbf{u}\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\|\mathbf{u}\|^2_2}}\mathbf{u}$ is differentiable ($G$ is the inverse of $F$).